# How to edit the words in TeX Live grammatically?

Tags: texmaker

I have a problem with editing the words in TeX Live?
When I installed the program, the program doesn't edit the words after typing,
that is, If I make a mistake with typing a word then I can't be noticed by the program,
while as I found from my friends it is impossible event. Why? How to solve this?

Comment: I don't understand your question at all. Please provide a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: looks like you don't have the right dictionary installed for you TeXmaker. Try Options => Configure TeXmaker => Editor and than change the dictionary

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please try to explain what you’re trying to do, and in which program: TeX Live is a *collection* of programs, and Texmaker a program that works *with* TeX Live but is not *part* of it.

Answer (score 2):

If you use TeXstudio as your IDE,then go to

`Configure Texstudio`, then click the `general` tab, under there you can find spelling dictionary directory and check whether you have set that ? if not select the correct language do you want.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).